# Dogecoin wallet console use full commands?

Tags: wallet, linux, ubuntu, dogecoin

I am looking for a list with `Dogecoin` wallet commands that I can run into linux terminal.

The interface seems useful, my pretty basic. For example, how can I check which is my wallet version?

This question is referring only `Dogecoin`  console commands if existing.

Comment: That's ridicules. The question is not duplicated since it is referring other type of wallet. Something more, it appears the dogecoin wallet has not support any type of commands.

Comment: Dogecoin is a fork of Litecoin and Litecoin is a fork of Bitcoin. All API commands are 100% repeatable with Litecoin, Dogecoin, with few exceptions.